# When i Instantiate an object and set variable it doesnt work in unity C#

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am trying to instantiate an object and when instantiated set a variable `uiManager` in the object being instantiated with a variable `uiManager` from the script `spawnPlayer`.

When I play and pause the game then look at the object instantiated, the variable is not set.

Heres the code!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playerSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] cars;
    public uiManager ui;

    int carSpawned;

    void Start ()
    {
        spawn ();
    }

    void spawn () 
    {
        Instantiate (cars [carPicController.next], transform.position, transform.rotation);
        carPicController.next = carSpawned; 
        Debug.Log ("player spawned");
        setuiManager ();
    }

    void setuiManager ()
    {
        //get the thing component on your instantiated object
        uiManager ui = cars [carSpawned].GetComponent<uiManager>();

        //set a member variable (must be PUBLIC)
        ui = ui;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for a standard thing for ya, all of my public methods and variables start with a capital and all of my private methods and variables start with a lowercase. As Andrew Shepherd pointed out below your code is basically setting the scope `ui` variable to itself. If you define your class `ui` variable as `Ui` you could have spotted this and also this will remove the extra characters for `this.ui` to `Ui`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is scoping.

This will work:

```
void setuiManager ()
{
    //get the thing component on your instantiated object
    uiManager ui = cars [carSpawned].GetComponent<uiManager>();

    //set a member variable (must be PUBLIC)
    this.ui = ui;
}
```

The problem is you have created a temporary variable with the same name as your class member. Inside the `setuiManager` it will assume `ui` is referring to the temporary variable, not the data member.